# How to read RTSP Video from OpenCV with Low CPU Usage?

Tags: python, opencv, cython

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://admin:admin123@10.0.51.110/h264/ch3/main/av_stream")
while(True):
    # Capture frame-by-frame
    ret, frame = cap.read()

    # Processing Frame -
    # Running Computer Vision Algorithm

    # Display the resulting frame
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
       break

# When everything done, release the capture
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This code is using nearby 50% of CPU Usage. How can we reduce this CPU Usage ?
    
    I have used time.sleep(0.05) but its delaying video feed processing, so won't work like realtime for me.

Comment: That 50% CPU usage is due to the fact that your stream is H264 encoded and the FFmpeg library is using the x264 codec to decode the stream.

Comment: what encoding should i set on camera ?

Comment: Read [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/529819/715573).

Comment: I have tried the code with mpeg1 encoded video, but it still use more CPU.

Answer (score 0):

Use Mjpeg as the codec and lower the fps ( frames per second) for video streaming source.

As mjpeg is less compressed as compared to H.264 , so bandwidth usage will be higher but your cpu usage will be less.